# Installation of certain es-lint extension packages fails

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

**Initial situation**

According to [this blog-post](https://dev.to/gsarciotto/migrating-and-configuring-eslint-with-angular-11-3fg1) it's good practise to use the following es-lint extensions for Angular projects:

```
@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat
@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on
@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates
```

Therefore the relevant part of my **.eslintrc.json** currently looks like this:

```
// ...
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "*.ts"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "project": [
            "tsconfig.json"
          ]
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
          "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
          "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
        ],
//...
```

**My issue**

In order for these extensions to take effect, the corresponding npm-libraries have to be added to the project as dev dependencies. Therefore I tried to execute the following command:

`npm install --save-dev @angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat`

Yet I get an error indicating that the library is not available anymore:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-eslint%2fng-cli-compat - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

The same error occured when I tried to install `@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on` or
`@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates`.

Is it no longer possible to install these libraries? If so, are there any recommended replacements, e.g. any other es-lint libraries that contain additional Angular-specific rules and settings?

Any help is welcome :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `ng-cli-compat` does no longer exist.

I would suggest to use `@angular-eslint/recommended` as this seems to be the community standard at the moment. This package also provides an `ng add` command to conveniently go trough the setup of eslint within an angular project (which uses angular-cli)

`ng add @angular-eslint/schematics`

Maybe also have a look at:

`plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended`

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of Riscie is basically right, I would like to add a few points that became clear to me upon further research:

Contrary to my initial assumption, the following plugins are **not** npm-libraries that can be installed as dev-dependencies:

```
"extends": [
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
]
```

Instead, these plugins represent **preset configurations** that are provided by npm-libraries. Specifically:

- `@angular-eslint/recommended` is a preset configuration provided by
  the npm-library `@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin`
- `@typescript-eslint/recommended` is a preset configuration provided by
  the npm-library `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`

And these npm-libraries in turn are **part of** the dev-dependencies that are installed when `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` is applied.